# Closure of $A:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ | \ 0 \leqq x \leqq 1, \ 0\leqq y \leqq1, \ x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\} $

Tags: real-analysis

$A:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ | \ 0 \leqq x \leqq 1, \ 0\leqq y \leqq1, \ x,y \in \mathbb{Q}\} $

I think the closure of $A$ is equal to $[0,1] \times [0,1].$

The reason is as follows.

Firstly, a neighbourhood of $(a,b) \ (a<0 \text{ or } 1<a \text{ or } b<0 \text{ or } 1<b) \ (:=N_{(a,b)})$ such that $N_{(a,b)}$ doesn't include any points of $A$ exists.

Secondly, any neighbourhood of $(a,b) \ (0\leqq a \leqq1 \text{ and } \ 0\leqq b \leqq 1)$ include a point of $A$, because of the density of rational numbers.

Is this idea correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It'll be more complete if you explicitly write down the thing that exists in your "Firstly" part.